# Javascript Get Values from Multiple Select Option Box

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, multiple-select

This one is driving me nuts. It’s got to be something simple and stupid that I am overlooking. 
I have a multiple select box in a form. I am just trying to get the values that are selected. In my loop, if I use alert then I have no problem. As soon as try to concatenate the values I get the error ‘SelBranch[...].selected' is null or not an object

```
      <form name="InventoryList" method="post" action="InventoryList.asp">
          <select name="SelBranch" class="bnotes" size="5" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="All">All</option>
          <option value="001 Renton">001 Renton</option>
          <option value="002 Spokane">002 Spokane</option>
          <option value="003 Missoula">003 Missoula</option>
          <option value="004 Chehalis">004 Chehalis</option>
          <option value="005 Portland">005 Portland</option>
          <option value="006 Anchorage">006 Anchorage</option>
          <option value="018 PDC">018 PDC</option>
          </select>

         <input type="button" name="ViewReport" value="View" class="bnotes" onclick="GetInventory();">

   </form>


   <script language="JavaScript">
       function GetInventory()
       {
         var InvForm = document.forms.InventoryList;
         var SelBranchVal = "";
         var x = 0;

         for (x=0;x<=InvForm.SelBranch.length;x++)
         {
            if (InvForm.SelBranch[x].selected)
            {
             //alert(InvForm.SelBranch[x].value);
             SelBranchVal = SelBranchVal + "," + InvForm.SelBranch[x].value;
            }
         }
         alert(SelBranchVal);
       }


  </script>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The for loop is getting one extra run. Change

```
for (x=0;x<=InvForm.SelBranch.length;x++)
```

to

```
for (x=0; x < InvForm.SelBranch.length; x++)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here i am posting the answer just for reference which may become useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show()
{
     var InvForm = document.forms.form;
     var SelBranchVal = "";
     var x = 0;
     for (x=0;x<InvForm.kb.length;x++)
         {
            if(InvForm.kb[x].selected)
            {
             //alert(InvForm.kb[x].value);
             SelBranchVal = InvForm.kb[x].value + "," + SelBranchVal ;
            }
         }
         alert(SelBranchVal);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
<select name="kb" id="kb" onclick="show();" multiple>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option selected="selected" value="US">US</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
</select>
<!--input type="submit" name="cmdShow" value="Customize Fields"
 onclick="show();" id="cmdShow" /-->
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [HTMLSelectElement.selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).

HTML

```
<select name="north-america" multiple>
  <option valud="ca" selected>Canada</a>
  <option value="mx" selected>Mexico</a>
  <option value="us">USA</a>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
var elem = document.querySelector("select");

console.log(elem.selectedOptions);
//=> HTMLCollection [<option value="ca">Canada</option>, <option value="mx">Mexico</option>]
```

This would also work on non-`multiple` `<select>` elements

---

**Warning:** Support for this `selectedOptions` seems pretty unknown at this point

Answer (score 2):

Also, change this:

```
    SelBranchVal = SelBranchVal + "," + InvForm.SelBranch[x].value;
```

to

```
    SelBranchVal = SelBranchVal + InvForm.SelBranch[x].value+ "," ;
```

The reason is that for the first time the variable `SelBranchVal` will be empty

Comment: Won't that just result in an extra comma at the end instead of an extra comma at the beginning?