# How to select multiple value from a listbox

Tags: javascript, select, listbox

I have a below code where if I select one value, it works fine, but now I need such that when I select multiple values from the listbox, i have to get the value of selected values. How do i go about it?
Here is the code,

HTML Code:

```
<select id="attributeNames" name="attributeNames" size="5" multiple="multiple"         
onchange="getUniqueValues(value)">
<option value="Apple"> Apple </option>
<option value="Mango"> Mango </option>
<option value="Orange"> Orange </option>
<option value="Banana"> Banana </option>                                            
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getUniqueValues(value){
alert(value);
}
```

For instance:
    If I select Apple, then I get alert saying apple, now if I select apple & mango, I have to get the alert having apple & mango values. Facing problem here.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/5VtE3/2/

Thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330030/javascript-get-values-from-multiple-select-option-box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do it -

HTML -

```
<select id="attributeNames" name="attributeNames" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Apple"> Apple </option>
    <option value="Mango"> Mango </option>
    <option value="Orange"> Orange </option>
    <option value="Banana"> Banana </option>                                            
</select>
```

​
JS -

```
window.onload = function () {
    var listbox = document.getElementById('attributeNames');
    listbox.onchange = function () {
        for(var index = 0; index < this.children.length; index++) {        
            if (this.children[index].selected) {
                console.log(this.children[index].value);
            }            
        }
    }​;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3jnQs/).

Answer (score 2):

If you dont mind using jquery, -

```
function getUniqueValues(){  
    var k=0;  
    var selected_list = {};  
    $('#attributeNames option').is(':selected').each(function(){  
        selected_list[k++] = $(this).val();  
        });  
    alert(selected_list);  
    }
```

OR

```
function getrUniqueValues(){  
    $('#attributeNames option').is(':selected').each(function(){  
        alert($(this).val());  
        });  
    }
```

Comment: @karaxuna: and so many times we forget that jQuery is _not_ JavaScript :-)

Comment: @SayemAhmed but we should consider that jQuery IS JavaScript :D

Comment: @karaxuna: I think we should consider jQuery as a _framework that changed the way we used to use JavaScript in web pages_, not JavaScript :-).

Comment: @SayemAhmed I've just joked. I know that when question is not tagged with jQuery, people don't want it (or don't know about it's existance). Anyway I think that jQuery alternative solutions are always good to see

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="apple">Apple<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="banana">Banana
```

Or you should just try to make:

```
<select id="attributeNames" name="attributeNames" size="5" multiple="multiple" onChange="getUniqueValues()" >
  <option value="Apple"> Apple </option>
  <option value="Mango"> Mango </option>
  <option value="Orange"> Orange </option>                                           
</select>

function getUniqueValues(){
var values = this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="attributeNames" onchange="getUniqueValues.call(this)" name="attributeNames" size="5" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Apple"> Apple </option>
    <option value="Mango"> Mango </option>
    <option value="Orange"> Orange </option>
    <option value="Banana"> Banana </option>                                
</select>

function getUniqueValues(){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++){
        if(this.options[i].selected)
            alert(this.options[i].value);
    }
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5VtE3/7/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getValue(id) {
                    var retval = "";
                    var lstdatabase = document.getElementById(id);
                    for (var i = 0; i < lstdatabase.options.length; i++) {
                        if (lstdatabase.options[i].selected) {
                            if (retval == "") {
                                retval = lstdatabase.options[i].value;
                            }
                            else {
                                retval = retval + ',' + lstdatabase.options[i].value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return retval;
                }
```