# In js, How can I set 2 and more select-option value to js code?

Tags: javascript

I want to make 2 and more select-option menus. 
My code is below,

```
 <select name="lang" id="lang">
    <option value="en">한국어,영어 동시</option>
    <option value="en">English, Corean</option>

    <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>

    <option value="ar">Arabic</option>
 </select>
 <select name="choice">
    <option value="1">disease code</option>
    <option value="2">disease name</option>

    <option value="3">drugs for treatment</option>
 </select>

  <p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
  <form> 
  Any Question : <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
  </form>
  <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
```

and, script code is below

```
 <script>
 function showHint(str)
 {
 if (str.length==0)
 { 
  .....
 }
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   ....
  {
 ....
  }
  }

 var selectedLang = document.getElementById('lang').value;
 var selectedChoice = document.getElementById('choice').value;
 xmlhttp.open("GET","ds_hint_"+selectedChoice+.+selectedLang+".php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
```

But, in script code, ds_hint_"+selectedChoice+.+....  may be wrong. 
How can i solve it in 2 select-option menu ?
Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
document.getElementById('choice').value;
```

the element you want to retrieve has to have the id attribute set to

```
id="choice"
```

You did not do that for the second select and I think that's why the URL is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<select multiple>` attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

And see this question for the script side of things

[Javascript Get Values from Multiple Select Option Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330030/javascript-get-values-from-multiple-select-option-box)