# If option 1 is selected in the dropdownlist then count++ in option 1 MySQL column using php( How Can I Do This ??)

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my drop down list, I would like to do something like when I choose employee 1 as my manager, then the num column of employee 1 will be count++. How can I do that. PLEASE HELP

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
 <select id='manager' name="manager" style='width: 200px;'>
 <option value="">Manager</option>
 <?php $sql = "SELECT FirstName,LastName,EmpId from tblemployees";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{   ?>                                            
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->EmpId);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->LastName);?> <?php echo htmlentities($result->FirstName);?></option>
<?php }} ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: have you thought about using javascript ajax for that ? Php you must call the same php file with a parameter that has your current count.

Comment: I've never think about using Javascript, how can I use it ?

Comment: see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621509/count-total-value-of-selected-options-using-javascript